# Bake frozen pizza without a tray - will it melt and drip?

Tags: baking, oven, pizza

How can frozen pizza be baked in an oven without a tray, without running the risk of melting like in the picture below (found on teh internets)? Or does that just not happen?

[image: Pizza baked through]

Comment: Probably depends on whether the dough is cooked first or whether it's just raw dough... But considering that the main way you get a nice, crisp dough is by putting the pizza on a very hot surface... You're really going to have quality issues if you try to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have baked many a frozen pizza without a tray and never had a pizza lose structural integrity like that.

The oven should be quite hot  (usually the box will specify at least 400°F).

Usually the difficulty arises when it's time to get the pizza out of the oven. I suggest a baking tray with no sides.

Comment: Indeed. Just baked it for 10 minutes at 425F and nothing leaked.

Comment: All of the frozen pizzas I've ever purchased actually tell you to put it right on the rack in the instructions!  What I've found works very nicely is a baking stone or a rimmed baking sheet turned upside down, with parchment between the stone and the pizza.  The parchment will not be hot, and you can pull the pizza out by the edge of the parchment.

Comment: Remember that parchment starts to crisp up and be very brittle at temperatures over 450°F. (Even if it doesn't spontaneously burst into flame as Ray Bradbury's Fahrenheit 451 would have you believe.)

Answer (score 3):

In the UK the instructions generally tell you to put the pizza directly on the shelf. This is what I always do and have never had problems. I can only see the above happening where someone has gotten used to doing this and then tried it with fresh dough.

Comment: That was my first thought too. Also, we had a similar problem, though not quite that bad, when I let the pizza thaw first, which is the same basic principle.

Comment: Most commercially produced frozen (or indeed chilled) pizza seems to be part-cooked already to have a fairly rigid base. Raw dough will behave slightly differently, or if the pizza is caked in ice it may get waterlogged and lose its rigidity, but I agree that the possibility is remote of it falling apart like that.

Answer (score -1):

Mine did completely that last night where it never did it before.  What a shock and a mess!  It was completely frozen so something must have been messed up with the ingredients. I won’t get that brand again!

Comment: Did you preheat the oven?  I have a suspicion that this is more likely to happen when the pizza thaws without cooking quickly.